# MAC Terminal error every time!!: -bash: xxxxx : is a directory

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

Whenever I open my terminal on my mac I get this message,
    -bash: source: /Users/macjem/: is a directory
How do I remove this? As I find it annoying and unneeded.

By the way my .bash_profile file is

```
PS1="\u$ "
alias ll="ls -lahG"
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
source ~/ .profile
```

and my bashrc file is

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`source ~/ .profile` was supposed to be `source ~/.profile`, with no space after `/`.